# Postgres DISTINCT Array

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table where there is column which has array of int.
The row have some unique array int or some have duplicate strings also

This is my query:

```
Select DISTINCT(F."Properties") FROM public."Firms" F,
LATERAL UNNEST(F."Properties") AS P
WHERE 
P = ANY(ARRAY[126])
AND F. "RegionId" = 7
AND F. "CityId" = 4365
```

**Query Result:**

[image]

I am expecting following output:

```
2
126
157
783...
```

Comment: Please post the complete query, the complete  results ( cannot tell what ... is) and the complete expected results. All as text - **no images**.  Provide this by **updating the question** not as an additional comment.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`